# Swift make func in extension "private" in same extension

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there a way to make the extension able to access private var defined in the definition file, but keep the extension's private function private to that extension only (not assessable in definition file)?

For example:

```
class MyClass {
  private var myStr = "str"
  func doSomething() {
    funcA() // <- should cause compiler error
  }
}

extension MyClass {
  private func funcA() {
    print(myStr)
  }
}
```

So doSomething() can not call funcA(), but funcA() can access myStr.

Comment: I haven’t tried myself but what about moving the extension to another file and making the function `fileprivate`? That being said, I personally prefer to use private before fileprivate

Comment: @Jessy Thanks for your suggestions. I fixed those in the updates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Put the definition in one file, and the extension in another.

> Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing
> declaration, and to extensions of that declaration that are in the
> same file.

That information is not quite complete. As you've seen, anything `private` *in an extension* is accessible in the declaration, and other extensions. But only in the same file.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html